# Is there a word for anti - or complete lack of political beliefs?

Tags: politics

*edit*
Basically, I'm trying to come up with a name for a new motorcycle club. I've been in others before and they seem to get ruined by politics and unnecessary alliances. I am hoping that there's a term (even if its Latin or something) that doesnt sound awful and describes a group of people who have no interest in politics or alliances or similar
*end of edit*

I'm looking for a word that describes someone or a group of people who either have an anti-political viewpoint or a complete disbelief in the workings of common politics. Perhaps a bit like an atheist with regards to religion.

Comment: You mean apolitical:?  https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/apolitical - or political agnostic?: http://www.tomorrowsreflection.com/political-agnostic/

Comment: What do you mean by "disbelief in the workings of common politics"? Do you mean a belief that the things politicians are doing are not working?  Or that politics isn't really happening?

Comment: Basically,  I'm trying to come up with a name for a new motorcycle club. I've been in others before and they seem to get ruined by politics and unnecessary alliances.  I am hoping that there's a term (even if its Latin or something)  that doesnt sound awful and describes a group of people who have no interest in politics or alliances or similar

Comment: Well, if it's going to be the name of a motorcycle club, then you're looking for a noun, not an adjective, so you might portmanteau the terms "politico," a noun for a highly political person, and "apolitical," an adjective that denotes a complete lack of politics, into the coined named "The Apoliticos."  If you want something more aggressive, connoting "anti-" more than "a-," then you might go with something like "The Pundit Punters," implying such dislike for politics that you kick anyone out who gets too vocal with their political opinions.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin.  If anyone else has any other ideas, I'd be very open to hearing ideas.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman An adjective could be used, too. E.g. The <word> Riders, where <word> is the answer to the question.

Comment: If, by politics, you mean 'party politics' rather than 'internal politics' or 'group politics' you could use the term 'non-partisan' which is the opposite of [partisan](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/partisan). I have in mind a name such as "The Non-Partisans' or, following @Barmar's suggestion, "The Non-Partisan Riders". If you wanted to make a pun on "party animal" you could call the group "The Non-Partisan Animals"

Comment: "Anti-political" is incendiary and can collapse into just another kind of politics. So I wouldn't use it. "Non-political" is neutre and respectful.

Answer (score 1):

Nonpolitical means not political and sounds fine.  That works for the meaning of having no interest or involvement in politics, for example, "We are a nonpolitical group."

Answer (score 0):

Apolitical means not interested or engaged in politics.

Impartial means to be neutral or not be biased. It's often used when referring to a television network that is meant to be politically neutral. It's also the term used when looking for polling station officials where I live.